# Combine a mutable string with an array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I'm completely new to objective C and need some help.

I have an array

```
NSArray *s = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"];
```

and by using a for loop, I want to return a mutable array with string that reads "this is number 1, this is number 2...for all the items in the array.

How do I do this? I've tried quite a few different things, and now I'm stuck.

Comment: So, what specifically does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can use `str = [str stringByAppendingString:newString];` method to concatenate two strings.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
  [newArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is number %@",array[i]]];
}
```